# Header on a header to CSV file

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a csv with two headers without index like this:

```
Inventory,,,,
PartNumber,Quantity,VendorName,FulfillmentCenterName,Delete
2056,00000037,cl Vendor,010039,0
2058,00000040,cl Vendor,010039,0
2065,00000083,cl Vendor,010039,0
2066,00000011,cl Vendor,010039,0
2067,00000000,cl Vendor,010039,0
```

My scripts starts downloading a file by API, and then I transform the it format to reduce the columns and rename again those.

My problem is that i can't to add the first header Inventory,,, . I just can add the second one.

This is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests
import io
import pandas as pd
import requests
import io

question = input('update data? y/n: ')

if question == 'y':

    print ('Actualizando...')
    url = 'http://.net/api/offers'

    r = requests.get(url, headers={'Authorization': 'aea2-a3e4a32afdc4'})
    i = io.StringIO(r.content.decode('utf-8'))
    OF51_ALL = pd.read_csv(i,sep=';', engine = 'python')
    cols = ['offer-id','quantity','shop-id','shop-name']
    OF51_ALL_SELECTED = OF51_ALL[cols]
    df = pd.DataFrame(OF51_ALL_SELECTED)
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:\\Users\\local\\parentfile.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
    writer.save()
    print ('update OK')

else: print('->')

datos = pd.read_excel(open('parentfile.xlsx','rb'), sheet_name = 'Sheet1')

datos['quantity'] = datos['quantity'].astype(str)
datos['offer-id'] = datos['offer-id'].astype(str)
datos['lenghts'] = datos['quantity'].apply(len)

datos.loc[(datos['lenghts'] == 1, 'new_col')] = '0000000'
datos.loc[(datos['lenghts'] == 2, 'new_col')] = '000000'
datos.loc[(datos['lenghts'] == 3, 'new_col')] = '00000'
datos.loc[(datos['lenghts'] == 4, 'new_col')] = '0000'
datos.loc[(datos['lenghts'] == 5, 'new_col')] = '000'
datos.loc[(datos['lenghts'] == 6, 'new_col')] = '00'
datos.loc[(datos['lenghts'] == 7, 'new_col')] = '0'
datos.loc[(datos['lenghts'] == 8, 'new_col')] = ''

datos['Quantity'] = datos['new_col']+datos['quantity']
datos.loc[(datos['lenghts'] <=8 , 'VendorName')]='cl Vendor'
datos.loc[(datos['lenghts'] <=8 , 'FulfillmentCenterName')]='010039'
datos.loc[(datos['lenghts'] <=8 , 'Delete')]='0'

datos.columns = ['PartNumber','quantity','shop-id','shop-name','len','z','Quantity','VendorName','FulfillmentCenterName','Delete']

eleccion = input('create: all or number?: ')

if eleccion == 'number':
    selecid = int(input('indicate: '))
    filtered=(datos.loc[datos['shop-id'] == selecid])
    indexdata = filtered.set_index('PartNumber')
    print (indexdata['shop-name'])
    print ('File was saved')
    indexdata.to_csv('C:\\file.csv', index = 'false', encoding = 'utf-8-sig', columns=['Quantity','VendorName','FulfillmentCenterName','Delete'])

elif eleccion == 'all':
    indexdata2 = datos.set_index('PartNumber')
    indexdata2.to_csv('C:\\file.csv',index = 'false', encoding = 'utf-8-sig', columns=['Quantity','VendorName','FulfillmentCenterName','Delete'])
    print ('File was saved')
else: print ('ERROR')
```

Comment: Why so many commas? Are there supposed to be blank headers?

Comment: Why do you comment on your own question? If you want to clarify it, you can [edit] it instead. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Oh, you mean you want multi-index?

Comment: I am equally as confused as the comments prior to me, but it looks like you are trying to convert to a csv where your column headers have a hierarchy.  You can eliminate this prior to writing to a csv by using `df.columns.droplevel()`

Answer (score 0):

I am equally as confused as the comments prior to me, but it looks like you are trying to convert to a csv where your column headers have a hierarchy. You can eliminate this prior to writing to a csv by using `df.columns.droplevel()`.

```
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([("Inventory", "PartNumber"), 
                                  ("Inventory", "Quantity") 
                                  ("Inventory", "VendorName")])
df = pd.DataFrame([[2056,00000037,cl Vendor], [2058,00000040,cl Vendor]], columns=cols)
df

-----------
Inventory   
PartNumber Quantity  VendorName
2056       00000037  cl Vendor
2058       00000040  cl Vendor
```

.

```
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()
df 
----------
PartNumber Quantity  VendorName
2056       00000037  cl Vendor
2058       00000040  cl Vendor

df.to_csv('filename.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

With this code, we are creating a csv file then we add the 2 lines header you wanted and then we fill with the data.

```
import csv

data = [("2056", "00000037", "c1 Vendor", "010039", "0"),
        ("2058", "00000040", "c1 Vendor", "010039", "0"),
        ("2065", "00000083", "c1 Vendor", "010039", "0"),
        ("2066", "00000011", "c1 Vendor", "010039", "0"),
        ("2067", "00000000", "c1 Vendor", "010039", "0"),]

with open('csv_file.csv', 'w', newline="") as csvfile:
    filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
                        quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    filewriter.writerow(['Inventory', '', '', '', ''])
    filewriter.writerow(['PartNumber', 'Quantity', "VendorName", "FulfillmentCenterName", "Delete"])
    for elt in data:
        filewriter.writerow(elt)
```